# (vb.net) Jumping between Impersonation and not?

Tags: sql, vb.net, impersonation

I am using impersonation to connect to an sql server and query its health.
Problem is I also have debugging and writing to disk and writing to eventlog.

The problem is that the account I impersonate as, does only have access to sql, but not to disk, eventlog and other stuff.

Do I really have to Login/logout 300 times ?

Login to get the query result, then logout to process it (writing debugging info), then log back in again to get some more info from sql, then back out again...

Tips?

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you need a way of passing data from a process under one identity to a process running under another identity?